# Troubles outputting array counter

Tags: java, arrays

I'm new to Java and I have a program players guess the price of an item (exact price is inputted first). I have an array called `winnerCount` which keeps track of the rounds won by each player. I want to output this using "JOptionPane.showMessageDialog" and part of the code involves giving each player a prize based on the rounds won. So for my pseudocode I have IF roundsWon = 1 THEN prize won: $15,125. When I try the same idea in Java it gives me the error "incomparable types" since its comparing `int` and `int[]`. Since Java can't compare different data types, what way(s) can I output the desired result ("winnerCount" and prizes won by each player)?

Here's what I'm working with

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.lang.Math;
import java.util.*;

public class priceIsRight {

 public static void main(String[] args) {

  double [] numPlayers = new double [4];
  double exactPrice = getExactPrices();
  double [] guessPrice = getGuessPrices(exactPrice);
  int roundsWon = getRoundsWon(guessPrice, exactPrice);
  int numRounds = 0;
  int [] winnersCount = new int [4];
  int roundWinner = getRoundsWon(guessPrice, exactPrice); 
  int prizesWon = calculatePrizesWon(winnersCount, roundWinner);

  }

 public static int getRoundsWon(double[] guessPrice, double exactPrice) {

    int roundWinner = getRoundsWon(guessPrice, exactPrice);
    int [] winnersCount = new int [4];
    int numRounds = 0;
    do {
       double minValue = Math.abs(exactPrice-guessPrice[0]);
       roundWinner = 0;
       for (int i=1;i < guessPrice.length; i++) {
           double diff = Math.abs(exactPrice-guessPrice[i]);
           if (diff<minValue) {
               minValue=diff;
               roundWinner=i;
           }
           winnersCount[roundWinner]++;
       }
       }
       while (numRounds <=3);
       return roundWinner;

   }


//Outputs result
     public static int calculatePrizesWon(int [] winnersCount, int roundWinner) {

     int prizesWon = 0;
     if (winnersCount = 0) {
        JOptionPane.ShowMessageDialog(null, "Prize won: $106 consolidation prize!");
        }
     else if (winnersCount = 1) {    
     JOptionPane.ShowMessageDialog(null, "Prize won: $15,125!");
        } 
     else if (winnersCount = 2) {    
     JOptionPane.ShowMessageDialog(null, "Prize won: $30,110!");
        } 
     else if (winnersCount = 3) {    
     JOptionPane.ShowMessageDialog(null, "Prize won: $15,120,000!");
        } 

    }
}
```

Comment: In your calculatePrizesWon method, you're using = (assignment operator) when you should be using == (equality operator)

Comment: I tried that as well and it still gives me the same error

Comment: It seems we do not understand if only `roundWinner` gets prizes or all the players do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify which location in the array you want to compare. Try this:

```
public static int calculatePrizesWon(int[] winnersCount, int roundWinner) {

    int prizesWon = 0;
    if (winnersCount[roundWinner] == 0) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Prize won: $106 consolidation prize!");
    } else if (winnersCount[roundWinner] == 1) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Prize won: $15,125!");
    } else if (winnersCount[roundWinner] == 2) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Prize won: $30,110!");
    } else if (winnersCount[roundWinner] == 3) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Prize won: $15,120,000!");
    }
    return prizesWon; // Replace this with the real prize won number.
}
```

You'll probably do better using a switch statement instead. If you want to see or receive comments on other things you can do better post a comment.

Comment: I'm sorry but what do you mean by switch statement? And this will display the rounds won by each player correct?

Comment: A [switch statement (link)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html) is a construct which allows you to compare a single value to many other values and do something when one of the conditions is met. It's basically a replacement for many if-else and will not affect functionality. Does my solution work for you? Does it at least not give you an error anymore?

Comment: and what else can I do better?

Comment: The only error I'm getting now is that it needs a return statement

Comment: I could turn this method into a void so it outputs the results I want but i would lose the calculatePrizesWon method since I won't be able to pass on the parameters. How can I return this method into my main?

Comment: I'm going to rewrite your code assuming I understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: If you want you can link it somewhere. The code in the question should remain the only part relevant to the question.

Comment: Have a look [here](http://pastie.org/9096691). Make sure you understand every place you went wrong. If any of us has answered your original question, feel free to accept it to "close the case".

Comment: Thanks for the code! I'll definitely learn from this. The notes that my instructor provides is pretty much useless (I am currently attending a university). By the way, I want to continue to learn and code java (and probably move onto other languages) but I won't be able to take classes for since I'm just taking java classes for fun. Are there any website that you'd recommend for a beginner to continue to learn and improve his skills?

Comment: @user3554678 For Java the best thing you can do to yourself is to read the [tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/). Start with `Trails Covering the Basics`. A more thorough book I personally like is `Thinking in Java / Bruce Eckel`. For other languages it really depends which.

Answer (score 0):

There are some things that don't make sense about this code.  For example, why did you make numPlayers a double[]?  Wouldn't it make more sense for it to be

```
int numPlayers = 4;
```

And for your winnersCount, is that storing how many rounds each player won?  If so then I assume your calculatePrizesWon method should be iterating through each player, and outputting their prize.

Something like

```
public static int calculatePrizesWon(int [] winnersCount, int roundWinner) 
{
    int prizesWon = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < winnersCount.length; i++)
    {
        if (winnersCount[i] == 0) 
        {
            JOptionPane.ShowMessageDialog(null, "Player "+i+" - Prize won: $106 consolidation prize!");
        }
        else if (winnersCount[i] == 1) 
        {    
            JOptionPane.ShowMessageDialog(null, "Player "+i+" - Prize won: $15,125!");
        } 
        else if (winnersCount[i] == 2) 
        {    
            JOptionPane.ShowMessageDialog(null, "Player "+i+" - Prize won: $30,110!");
        } 
        else if (winnersCount[i] == 3) 
        {    
            JOptionPane.ShowMessageDialog(null, "Player "+i+" - Prize won: $15,120,000!");
        } 
    }
}
```

Also, what is the "round winner" parameter you're passing into calculatePrizesWon for?
And what is the "prizesWon" variable for?  If, for example, a player won three rounds, then wouldn't they also have won three prizes?  So what distinction is there between the winnersCount and the prizesWon?
I'll try to help but you'll need to explain what you're doing a little more clearly.

Comment: When I tried to use int numPlayer, I got an error saying that it required double but found int, so I changed it to double. roundWinner is the method where it finds out which player won how many rounds. I forgot to edit out int prizesWon sorry!